# Jackson and serialization

Tags: serialization, hashmap, jackson, javabeans

I have a problem with my web project. I'm using jackson, and have problem with serialization. When i try to return a hashmap back to page this is message of the error:

```
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:644)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:152)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:541)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:644)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:152)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedListSerializer.serializeContents(IndexedListSerializer.java:100)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedListSerializer.serializeContents(IndexedListSerializer.java:21)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.AsArraySerializerBase.serialize(AsArraySerializerBase.java:183)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:541)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:644)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:152)
```

I implemented serializable in my bean and it has empty constructor,getters and setters.

Comment: The top of the exception message is missing.  Could you add the full exception stack trace you are receiving?

Comment: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain: beans.Kategorija["podkategorija"]->beans.Kategorija["podkategorije"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->beans.Kategorija

Comment: @JsonIgnore solved it, for now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its probably because you have a child object, and one of its elements contains the parent object, so jackson is trying to serialize the child object, creating again a serialized  parent, which will cause the parent to create again a serialized child, and the child will cause a serialized parent again, so its a never ending loop for jacokson.